# Convert URI to String

Tags: vb.net

Visual Basic 2010.

```
Dim selection As String = ListBox1.SelectedItem
Dim url As String = Split(selection, " - ")
Form1.WebBrowser1.Navigate(url(1))
```

I want to convert the URI (Value of type '1-dimensional array of string' cannot be converted to 'string') to a string. How would I do so?

(The selection variable is something like "Title - URL")

Thanks!

- The error is on `Split(selection, " - ")`

Comment: why cant u use ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() instead of, you used?

Comment: @kalyan it gives me the same error.

Comment: Can, you tell at which part of the code the Error is coming exactly?

Answer (score 3):

May be your error is at Getting the Split Parts of the Selection to the Url, where you have used normal string instead of One-Dimensional Array Declaration.

Comment: Thank you! I have solved this problem by using.. Dim url As Array = Split(selection, " - ")

Answer (score 0):

Split function will return array of string. But you are trying to assign its value to "string". To declare a array use the below code

```
Dim url() As String = Split(selection, " - ")
```

To know about vb array refer the link.
http://www.startvbdotnet.com/language/arrays.aspx

Also one wise way to store url in ListItem is, Set the URL in `Value` field and Display text in `Text` field. So that, you can retrieve url from value easily without any string processing.